# "This pair of shoes is too dirty." When we mention the shoes again, which pronoun is more common? It or them?

Tags: pronouns

> This pair of shoes is too dirty. _______, please!.
>
> A. Take them away
>   B. Take it away

This is a question from my English exercise book. The answer is **A**, but I think **B** also makes sense. Because **them** corresponds to **shoes**, **it** corresponds to **pair**.

Am I right?

If I am right, which one is more common, **A** or **B**?

Comment: I suppose *it* is ‘algorithmically’ correct, but *them* is sounds more idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 6):

*B* might make sense, but it's not idiomatic. It's true that *pair* is a count noun  in that you can have *one pair* or *two pairs*. But when you are referring to *both shoes of the pair*, we use a plural pronoun.

So, it's *take them away* because both shoes are dirty.

If only one shoe of the pair of shoes is dirty, we wouldn't normally  say *this pair of shoes is dirty* but *this shoe is dirty* or *the right/left  shoe (of this pair of shoes)* is dirty. In that case you're talking about one shoe so use *it*: *Take it (the dirty shoe) away*.

Again  if only shoe was dirty and you said *Take them away*, you might get a puzzled look from whoever you're talking to, because they would associate *it* not with *one pair* but with *one shoe*; thus they might wonder why you're saying to take only one dirty shoe away if both are dirty. Yes, it might "make sense" to say *Take it away* and have *it* refer to *the pair of dirty shoes*, but that's not how native speakers normally use and match the pronouns with the nouns in this context.

Comment: To expand on this, both "It's a nice pair of shoes" and "They're a nice pair of shoes" are both idiomatic.  It relects that, when talking about a group of something, we can use singular for the group **or** plural, for the members of the group.  Each shifts attention in a slightly different way.